How to dynamically add rows to an Excel table when the table name is determined by a Compose action?
I’m working on a Power Automate flow where each week is stored in a separate tab (worksheet) in an Excel workbook. Each tab contains a table with the same structure, and the name of the table matches the week name.
The flow determines which table to use dynamically based on a Compose action that outputs the week name. I’m using this output to specify the Table name in the "Add a row into a table" action.
Here’s the issue:
When I manually select a static table name, Power Automate auto-generates the Advanced Parameters with all the column names, making it easy to map form data to table columns.
However, when I use the dynamic Compose output for the table name, the column names do not appear in the Advanced Parameters, and I’m unable to map the form data directly to the table columns.
So far I've tried to use "Get Table" so I can fetch the column names in advance but I'm not sure how to do that.

Bottom line, you need to know the field names.

Given you've taken the dynamic approach, you have to provide the data in a JSON object format without the use of the dynamic properties that are generated when you map the table directly.
This shows you the basic approach, you simply need to create the JSON object and the field names need to marry with the field names in the table.

Note: If any field name has full stops/periods and other no alpha type characters then you'll need to find the exact name.  The best way to do this is to create a hard link to the workbook and the table in an Add rows to table step to find out the exact names.  Do that and then look at the Code view on the step to see what they are.
The below images contain a static link to a workbook and table, it's not setup dynamic like the previous image.


